# Is question 115686 too subjective?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In comments to [How can one-handed work in Ubuntu be eased?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115686/how-can-one-handed-work-in-ubuntu-be-eased#comment137786_115686) it is argued that it is subjective in that there is no correct answer to it per se. What is your thoughts?

Comment: Related: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it is not too subjective, at least not compared to other questions. Seeing that the question already has useful answers it is possible to answer. Any question where it is hard to tell what would be most useful for the OP is subjective in a sense, but if this seen as a reason for closing questions *lots* of questions will have to be closed.

Also, questions based on actual problems are encouraged. This question is based on an actual practical problem, namely that when a user suddenly only can use one hand, then Ubuntu (as most other systems) is less efficient and more straining to interact with.

Finally, it might be argued that the question is too general and therefore subjective. I think not. It makes sense to pose the problem generally because using Ubuntu with one hand, rather than two, is a general problem. It is a problem that some users are likely to face (of course, this does not mean that particular questions on using certain programs with one hand lose force). Some solutions to using a particular program with one hand are applicable to any program because they rely on something external to that program, e.g. some system feature. Such solutions are fitting answers to a question on using Ubuntu with one hand.

Comment: Its not subjective.

Comment: This is a great explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

*It is not a subjective question, as to extract a certain response.*

This question could be put into any forum that pertains to a general question format.

The question was asked as to gain incite to the possibility of other apparatus or applications to assist in the daily functions of typing, using one hand.

That kind of question is applauded.+1 "How else my I assist you"? Should be the next part of the answer!

The question was not asked to gain sympathy, meant to extract an opinion nor was it derogatory. The Ask Ubuntu forum should be proud to help out. My personal opinion may be subjective, just ask me.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your position. Is your first paragraph an argument for or against the question being subjective?

Comment: I am afraid your edit did not make me understand better. What do you mean by "as to extract a certain response"? Why do you mention that the question could be put in any forum (this is Q&A)?

Comment: The question was not worded in a manner to make the reader have a certain opinion. You were not forcing your opinion on any one else.

Comment: How does that relate to whether it is a subjective question? I take it that a question is subjective in the relevant sense if the criteria for a good answer to that question *only* has to do with the OP's opinion.

Comment: Go back to the first comment you made. The paragraph you refer to. I made a statement *FOR* your question. (the question is *NOT* a subjective one). Therefore, I agree with -JRG. I also agree with -Manish Sinha.